# Run setInterval immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to execute a setInterval function immediately after a button is pressed, then run the function every 5 seconds.

Why does this work:

```
$(function () {

    $('button').on('mousedown', function () {

        var checkUser = setInterval(function () {

        }, 5000);

    checkUser();

    });

});
```

But not this:

```
$(function () {

    $('button').on('mousedown', function () {

        var checkUser = setInterval(function () {

        }(), 5000);

    });

});
```

Comment: So call the function and than set the interval with a reference to the function.

Comment: Your second example is not working because you're not auto-invoking the function correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/7fwryuy0/ . But epascarello's answer is what you should be looking for, it's not worth investing random parenthesis with random function names when you can reference a function (... Or use a setTimeout...!)

Comment: You can also [do it this way](http://jsfiddle.net/cjpco08j/4/), but it's also a bit long-winded.

Comment: @Andy: wouldn't it be easier to return the same function? your example is very interesting though!

Comment: I think you missed out the quotes around "interesting" :)

Comment: @Andy, how would I clearInterval from outside the function in your jsfiddle example?

Comment: Good point. [I've updated the example to make it even more complicated](http://jsfiddle.net/cjpco08j/12/).

Comment: It's much more practical to use @epascarello's example tho which is why I upvoted that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first one is not executing a function to start as you think it is. Interval retruns an id, not a reference to the method being called. There should be an error in the console.

The second one is calling the function and storing what the function returns as the interval. In your case it is not returning anything so it is storing undefined.

Store the function, reference it, and call it.

```
$(function () {

    $('button').on('mousedown', function () {
        var myFunc = function () {

        };
        var checkUser = setInterval(myFunc, 5000);
        myFunc();
    });

});
```

or use Timeout instead of interval.

```
$(function () {

    $('button').on('mousedown', function () {
        var myFunc = function () {
            /* do stuff */
            setTimeout(myFunc, 5000);    
        };
        myFunc();
    });

});
```